# how to restore a multiple-server farm to a single-server farm ? SP2013

Tags: 2013, backup, restore

We try to do a farm backup but it didn't work because it was a restore a multiple-server farm to a single-server farm.

What are the option to backup/restore a multiple-server farm to a single-server farm? I would like to stay away from deploying WSPs.

Comment: You will still need to deploy wsps as the same features in the multi sever farm need to be on the single server farm in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your sitution i would prefer the Content Database Attach approach.

- Install sharepoint on server(same version/build level)
- Configure the farm
- create Services Applications
- Create Web Application (as per requirement)
- Deploy all the customitzation/wsp you have in production
- now backup the content Database from Prodction(multi Server farm)
- restore on the single server farm sql server
- Now attach the content database to desired web app
- run the full crawl(if search service configured)
- any special settings apply now.

You will be all set now, One thing you need new DNS for single server or you can use server name and port number.